# Copy users from multiple AD-groups to new AD-Groups using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to copy multiple users from a pair of 2 or 3 groups to one new group.
There are 30 groups which needs to be moved to 10 new groups.

```
Example:
Oldgroup1, Oldgroup2, Oldgroup3 > NewGroup1
Oldgroup4, Oldgroup5 > NewGroup2
```

I am thinking of foreach loop but can not figuer out how to bind multiple old groups to new group as members from old groups can be diff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Organize the mapping between new and old groups in a dictionary:

```
$groupMappings = @{
  'NewGroup1' = 'Oldgroup1', 'Oldgroup2', 'Oldgroup3'
  'NewGroup2' = 'Oldgroup4', 'Oldgroup5'
}
```

Then for each mapping entry:

- Fetch the members of the old groups
- Remove duplicates from result
- Add them to the new group

```
foreach($entry in $groupMappings.GetEnumerator()){
  # Fetch members of all the old groups, keep only unique set of users
  $members = $entry.Value |Get-ADGroupMember |Where-Object objectClass -eq user |Sort-Object -Unique objectGUID

  # Add them all, one by one (this way the whole request wont fail if any one member is already a member of the target group)
  foreach($member in $members){
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $entry.Name -Member $member
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works I just need to change -Member to -Members in last line.